# Django: ContentType object access, Get user from the content_object

Tags: python, django, django-models

Helllo everyone, I have no solution to Get User who owns the Content Object in Django. So I post for your guys help!

I'm building 2 models: Reaction and Notification. If user React, Notification will auto be created a object. This is my code:
Model Reaction:

```
class Reaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    react_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=REACT_TYPES, default='NO')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
       Notification(from_user = self.user, to_user = ???, notification_type = Notification.LIKED, target_content_type = self.content_type, target_object_id = self.object_id).save()
       super(Reaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Models Notification

```
class Notification(models.Model):    
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_user_noti')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_user_noti')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='notify_target', blank=True, null=True)
    target_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_content_type', 'target_object_id')
```

As you saw, I have problem with get `to_user` fields. This field I want to get **User who owner a Content Object in Django** Example: Post, Comment, ...
Please help me with this case!

Comment: In `Notification` you should have different `related_name` for `from_user` and `to_user`, and those related_names should be alphanumeric, not '+'.

Comment: Sorry I make mistake from copy paste. I changed it!!

Comment: Well, you can have another to_user field in Reaction model.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal I thinks this solution is make more slot in database. Any solution?

Comment: What about the reaction model having a foreignkey to Notification model ? You might need to consider restructuring the models.

Comment: Any solution which I can get User own ContentType Object? @SandeepBalagopal

Comment: Maybe you ought to save the reaction object(super call) before the Notification object creation. If the content_object always has a user then you can directly access it using instance.content_object.user and can use it to assign as to_user in notification object, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this, assuming that the content_object has a user relation:

```
class Reaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    react_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=REACT_TYPES, default='NO')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
       super(Reaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       Notification(from_user = self.user, to_user = self.content_object.user, notification_type = Notification.LIKED, target_content_type = self.content_type, target_object_id = self.object_id).save()
```

Comment: I got this error @RajKris AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: was the content_object saved(for the reaction object)?

Comment: Sorry about that.The super actually does not return anything. Updated the code. Please check.